# Почему не создаётся статья? (yii2 -advanced)

Tags: php, yii2, phpmyadmin

Imagik вроде бы установлен уже в папке vendor в проекте, в настройках Open Server PHP-7.0, Apache-7 MySQL-5.5

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: Вам нужно вывести phpinfo(); чтобы быть точно уверенным что расширение установлено.

Comment: если в командной строке вводить это, то ошибка синтаксиса. а так в папке D:\sites\interjobs\vendor\imagine\imagine\lib\Imagine\imagick он есть

Comment: Нет, не в командной строке, а вывести на странице. PHP CLI и PHP FPM могут иметь разный набор расширений и вообще быть разных версий.

Comment: Посмотрите и проверьте что расширение было установлено как в описании на http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-extensions.html. Просто так скачать расширение, не указав где оно, не получится, а указывать можно в composer.json или в конфигурационном файле приложения.

Comment: в основном composer.json есть "yurkinx/yii2-image": "dev-master",  а phpinit где нужно выводить? у меня модуль arcticle подключен в vendore, я открываю его в backend. т.е нужно в Arcticle.php вставить <?php

// Показать всю информацию, по умолчанию INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

// Показать только информацию модуля.
// phpinfo(8) даст идентичный результат.
phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);

?>

Comment: @Sandro_s, интересно, разобрались?)

Comment: вместо Imagik поставил пока GD